# how to get latitude & longitude from google location services in android

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager, android-location, locationlistener

I've successfully implemented LocationListener and could get geo coordinates from GPS. Now I am looking to implement the same and get latitude, longitude from Google location services.
is this different from getting location from GPS ? could not find enough info. 
Help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also you could write a code which chooses the best provider to obtain the most correct location.

Here is a very good tutorial at how to use Google Location Service API:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html

Another good information provider is Android's Developers Web Page:
[Location and Sensors](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/index.html)

Comment: that's really good resource. thanks for that.
Although this link gives me good solutions, I am just curious to know how to get geo coordinates from google location services. Most of the internet stuff i found explains me on using GPS provider but could not find enough info on  either google location services or mobile wireless (Cell) providers. any clue on that ?

Comment: There are two ways to obtain current location - via GPS data or via NETWORK (Cell) data. 

You want to obtain your current location via network provider, right? 
If so the way to do that is the same as when you obtaining your location via GPS provider except you are choosing NETWORK_PROVIDER to be used by LocationManager. 

If it's not the case, please provide more information of what you want to do. :)

Comment: i could implement that without any errors but it does not give me any location updates. I think now I should look upon the working of Google location services.

Answer (score 0):

The code will be the same to read the coordinates.  To read it from Google Location Services, you would set up a listener for network rather than GPS provider.

Instead of `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER`, you would use `LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER`.

Comment: thanks for your reply Shah.
I did that part, now I am looking for a way to know if that connection is established and providing me location updates (for example, gps_fix that we do for GPS provider).